# Apple's 'Swift-Format' versus Nick Lockwood's 'SwiftFormat'

Tags: swift

I've been using Nick Lockwood's [SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat) for months if not years; and I'm completely satisfied with it.

Now is see Apple has its own [Swift-Format](https://github.com/apple/swift-format); which requires [SwiftSyntax](https://github.com/apple/swift-syntax).

Swift-Format appears to be over-engineered compared to SwiftFormat. 
What's the difference between the two? 
Why have Swift-Format when SwiftFormat has been around for awhile?

Comment: You may have found this, though others may not have.  Here's an interesting read on the topic from the [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-an-official-style-guide-and-formatter-for-swift/21025): it's the pitch for creating swift-format in the first place.  Maybe it can help understand the motivations.  I didn't read through the entire comment chain yet, but they do bring up the prevalence of SwiftFormat in the community early on in the discussion.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by [Sean Skelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3791245/sean-skelly) there's some big discussion about "community vs official tools". I think [this one comment](https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-an-official-style-guide-and-formatter-for-swift/21025/228) contains valid explanation:

> Done right, an official tool would channel the community’s energy and therefore be of higher quality than could be achieved via independent competing open source projects.

Of course if official tool is implemented not so great or it's development strategy lacks something – it won't work – which is also stated in the same comment:

> Done poorly, a standard tool would be unfortunately limited relative to competing open source projects but would zap the energy and motivation to continue developing those tools.